# How to convert this FILTER + COUNTA() into an Arrayformula on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got this one working fine, but it'd have to be an arrayformula:

```
=if(A3="","", COUNTA(filter(D:D,regexmatch(LOWER(D:D), LOWER(A3)))))
```

I have tried it like this, but it gives a total only in the cell the formula sits:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A3:A="","", COUNTA(filter(D:D,regexmatch(LOWER(D:D), LOWER(A3:A))))))
```

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing) the demo file.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(D3:D, 
 "select D,count(D) 
  where D is not null 
  group by D 
  label count(D)''")
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({FILTER(D3:D, D3:D<>""), 
 FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REGEXMATCH(FILTER(D3:D, D3:D<>"")&"", ""&
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A3:A, A3:A<>"")))*1), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D3:D))&")")),2))}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A3:A="",,
 REGEXMATCH(IF(A3:A="",,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D3:D, D3:D<>""))), A3:A)+0)), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A3:A))&")")), 2)))
```

[image]

---

### update 3:

if column A contains empty cells in between

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A3:A="",,
 REGEXMATCH(IF(A3:A="",,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D3:D, D3:D<>""))), A3:A)+0)+0), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(MAX((A3:A<>"")*ROW(A3:A))-ROW(A3)+1)&")")), 2)))))
```

[image]

---

### update 4:

one more alternative

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(1/(1/IF(A3:A="",,
 REGEXMATCH(IF(A3:A="",,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D3:D, D3:D<>""))), A3:A)+0)))),,9^9))), " ", )))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Sorry if I wasn't clear in my explanation, but it count the occurrences of values in column A, so there is a comparison in the game. Thanks!

Comment: Here's my adaptation based on your response: ```=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(vlookup(A3:A,QUERY(D3:D1000,"select D, COUNT(D) where D is not null group by D label count(D)''"),2,0)))``` but it doesn't count occurrences that contain A column's values

Comment: @onit answer updated

Comment: Swewar I'm trying alternatives here, but I get ```Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC```

Comment: @onit I can reproduce that error only if A column contains empty cells. is that your case with real dataset? answer updated

Comment: @onit added one more alternative

Comment: Incredible!!!!!!!!!!!!
I've tried them all and for some reason none of them gives the result in the file shared in the question!

Comment: @onit see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1btswrO7b6Stqc1VX5JyLSV30A0yyO6ilC7ynheId04E/edit#gid=1644713732

Comment: Got it! THANKS A MILLION once again!